# Event handler with functions which have arguments

Tags: javascript, html

what is the proper way to have an event handler call a method which needs arguments e.g

```
<input type="button" name="Blue" value="blue" onclick=bgcol("blue")>
```

All attributes should have used "" e.g with name, name="blue" however if i do this for the onclick it wont work since it can't match the speech marks. THis code does work however isn't validated using w3 validator. 
So whats the proper way to do this? bgcol is a function which takes an argument colour and simply sets the background colour to that argument. Can this be done using only one function bgcol?

Comment: Use HTML5 `data-` attributes.?

Comment: In general, you should use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead of intrinsic event attributes.

Comment: You don't use attribute handlers. That's how. Read about `addEventListener()`

Comment: @Quentin thank you instead i can do 
    
    `onclick="bgcol('blue')"`>